# JavaScript splice more than 1 value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to `splice` the string value so the output only become `'LA1','LA4'`. I tried the method below but it still gave me `string_2` output.

```js
var string_1 = 'LA2,LA3'
var string_2 = "LA1,LA2,LA3,LA4";

var unique_1 = string_1.split(',');
var unique_2 = string_2.split(',');

const index = unique_2.indexOf(unique_1);
if (index > -1) {
  unique_2.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(unique_2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `splice()` You can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var string_1 = 'LA2,LA3'
var string_2 = "LA1,LA2,LA3,LA4";

var unique_1 = string_1.split(',');
var unique_2 = string_2.split(',');

var filtered = unique_2.filter(s => !unique_1.includes(s))

console.log(filtered);
```

If your lists are very large, you might want to use something other than an array with `includes()` such as a `Set` that offers constant time lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.indexOf() only finds one element and can not find an array.
To get the expected value, you can do as follows.

```
var string_1 = 'LA2,LA3'
var string_2 = "LA1,LA2,LA3,LA4";

var unique_1 = string_1.split(',');
var unique_2 = string_2.split(',');

unique_2 = unique_2.filter(item => !unique_1.includes(item));

console.log(unique_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

using reduce:

```js
var string_1 = 'LA2,LA3'
var string_2 = "LA1,LA2,LA3,LA4";

var unique_1 = string_1.split(',');
var unique_2 = string_2.split(',');

const result = unique_2.reduce((acc, item) => {
  !string_1.includes(item) && acc.push(item)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```